# using columns from 2 different workbooks to make an if statement in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have variables, yes_n and yes_d. D for denominator and n for numerator. I have workbook A, the flat file, and workbook B, the reference file. I am trying to pull columns from two different workbooks and then if the words in a cell in workbook A, sheet A, column A = the words in a cell in workbook B, sheet, column B and the words in the column to the left of cell B are yes then add one to my variable yes_d. Then after, if the words in cell D of workbook A are "some value" then add 1 to the numerator also.  How do I say something like "If cellA(workbookA.SheetA.columnA) = cellB(workbookB.SheetB.columnB) AND the offset of B = "yes" then yes_d + 1. If cellDworkbookA.SheetA.columnD) = "some value" then yes_n + 1.

```
For M = 2 To 1000
    For R = 2 To 60

        If Workbooks("\flatfile.xlsb").Worksheets("ifyesorno").Range("A" & M) = _
           Workbooks("\referencefile.xlsm").Worksheets("reference1").Range("B" & R)_
            And Workbooks("\referencefile.xlsm").Worksheets("reference1").Range("A"_
            & R).Value = "yes" Then

            yes_d = yes_d + 1

            If Workbooks("\flatfile.xlsb").Worksheets("ifyesorno").Range("D" & M) = "some value" Then

                yes_n = yes_n + 1

            End If
        End If

    Next
Next
```

Comment: Should yes_n be incremented ONLY IF yes_d is incremented?  e.g. if the value in column A of ifyesorno = the value in column B of reference1, but column A of reference1 is "no", should yes_n still be incremented if column D of ifyesorno = "some value"?

Comment: column A of reference1 will be an arbitrary value not necessarily yes or no. I should have explained that better, so yes_d is always incremented if the first if statement is true and only if both the second if statement is true AND the first if statement is true does yes_n get incremented

Comment: Where is your code currently not working?  Is it as you refer to `Workbooks("\flatfile.xlsb")`?  (I think that should just be `Workbooks("flatfile.xlsb")`, i.e. get rid of the "\".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your code already meet your criteria.  You were improperly referencing the open workbooks. If the workbooks are not open then you'll have to open them.  A space is needed between the code and line continuation `_`.

Incorrect: `.Range("B" & R)_`

Correct  `.Range("B" & R) _`

Creating variables to shorten references will greatly improve the readability of your code.

```
Dim wsFlat As Worksheet, wsReference As Worksheet
Set wsFlat = Workbooks("flatfile.xlsb").Worksheets("ifyesorno")
Set wsReference = Workbooks("referencefile.xlsm").Worksheets("reference1")

For M = 2 To 1000
    For R = 2 To 60

        If wsFlat.Range("A" & M) = wsReference.Range("B" & R) And wsReference.Range("A" & R).Value = "yes" Then

            yes_d = yes_d + 1

            If wsFlat.Range("D" & M) = "some value" Then
                yes_n = yes_n + 1
            End If
        End If

    Next
Next
```